# How do I issue refund with BlueSnap API

Tags: api, e-commerce, bluesnap

I need refund transactions in BlueSnap, I'm using API and I have invoice numbers.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't mention which type of API integration you're using, so here are your options:

If you are using Payment API (JSON/XML) - 
Use PUT with this URL format: https://ws.bluesnap.com/services/2/transactions/:transaction-id/refund

More details:
https://developers.bluesnap.com/v8976-JSON/docs/refund
https://developers.bluesnap.com/v8976-XML/docs/refund

If you are using Extended Payment API  - see the explanation in this link.

Use PUT with this URL format:
https://ws.bluesnap.com/services/2/orders/refund?invoiceId=38410844&reason=unsatisfied+customer

More details:
https://developers.bluesnap.com/v8976-Extended/docs/refund-invoice

Comment: Thanks - I'll check it out